# From a place outside my home network how can I use RDP to connect to a computer at home that is using a vpn

Tags: vpn, remote-desktop, desktop

Sorry for the loaded question, but its rather specific.

So, I have a second computer that I currently use a VPN with a static IP on. I would like to be able to control this computer remotely while it is connected to the vpn. I am able to forward the connection so that I am able to connect to my it on the home network's IPv4 (When not connected to the vpn) but if it is connected to the VPN, it receives no respond / the connection is terminated if I connect to the VPN while connected. How can I get around this.

Please let me know if I'm leaving out any crucial information. Thank you

Comment: This is really more in the realm of networking than of security, but you can a) try to control if from the end of the VPN it's connected to or b) stand up a virtual interface (not sure how that works with windows, I'm a Linux guy) or c) get it a second network adapter that stays connected to the home network while the VPN is active.

Comment: What components are involved, how are they connected? Where does the VPN connection start and terminate?

Comment: Looks like the VPN is configured to disallow any local non-VPN traffic. In this case you need to open a second connection to the VPN system and connect to the computer using the IP it got inside the VPN connection.